# How recent is the usage of “concerning” meaning “worrying”?

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english

I’m used to “concerning” meaning

> relating to or having to do with; in regard to; about

Now I see it more often in the sense of “worrying” as in “this is very concerning.”

Is this a particularly new usage?

I’m aware of Google Ngrams. Not sure how to apply it to this question though.

Comment: Corporate-speak substitutes bland language for accuracy. There are no problems, only issues ... and concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of "concern" to mean "worry" is quite old. As one example, the text ["An Account of the Revival of Religion in Boston in the Years 1740-1-2-3," published in 1823](https://archive.org/details/anaccountreviva00pringoog/page/n7/mode/1up?q=Concern), contains the following (p. 21, my emphasis):

> O sleeper! awake, and hearken, there is a noise and a shaking among the dry bones. Some it may be of your own acquaintances, secure like you a little while ago, are now in deep **concern**, and can no longer relish those carnal pleasures in which you were companions. Now, destruction from God is a **terror** to them, and they are fleeing from the wrath to come.

He appears (though the scan is imperfect) to be quoting a speech given in 1741, so this usage is likely far older.

Answer (score -1):

“I’m aware of Google ngrams. Not sure how to apply it to this question though.”

Seems I didn’t try hard enough :-/

I looked up “very concerning, mildly concerning, somewhat concerning”

It looks like this usage started in the early 90s.

There’s nothing wrong with the usage if it expresses something causing “mild concern” as opposed to something making you “very worried”.

In the old days I suppose we had to make do with “disquieting” or something “being cause for concern”.

Comment: The full OED covers this usage in definition 3: *That gives cause for concern; troubling, vexing* (mildly, or extremely - the word itself carries no special implication on that front). But their first citation is **1740**  ( S. Richardson Pamela II. 159) *I cannot bear any thing that is the least **concerning** to you.*

Comment: I added the modifier “very” because you can’t just search for “concerning” — that would give you *all* usages. The usage of “very concerning” shoots up, starting in the early 90s. There’s a nearly 200 year gap where that phrase hardly appears at all, according to Google ngrams.

Comment: You might want to look at "deeply concerning" in comparison to "very concerning" too.

Comment: Well, the OED's *next* cite is 150 years after the first. But it does specifically use intensifier ***very*** - **1890**  F. A. Randle Imgar (ed. 2) iv. 18   *They soon became rather numerous and **very concerning**, pelting the Hindoos with pebbles and rolling large rocks down ahead obstruently.* Then it's another century until we get **1987**   Daily Tel. 19 Feb. 40/6   *It is **concerning** that an MP and a Minister could suggest that you actually have to be a member of Parliament in order to have an opinion.* Probably just reasons of space, not that they *couldn't* "fill in the gaps".

Comment: @Killing Time: The “deeply” versus “very” comparison is indeed interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is the second sense in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concerning):

> concerning (2 of 2)
> adjective
> : causing concern or worry : creating reason for concern : TROUBLING
> *"It's extremely concerning that drivers still choose to give their attention to things other than the road when they're behind the wheel," said [Texas Department of Transportation] Executive Director James Bass.
>
> —The Nueces County Record Star*

This sense is derived from the adjective "concerned". The [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concerned) definition  is:

> 1a: ANXIOUS, WORRIED
> concerned for their safety
> *Concerned citizens protested the mayor's proposal.*

Comment: This doesn't address the question of how recent it is.